# Put a link (back) to the main site review page on the meta site review page

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design, meta

On the [Stack Overflow review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), there is a link to the MSO review page:

[image: SO review page]

Can we have similar link to Stack Overflow review page on the [MSO review page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review)?

[image: MSO review page]

Now if someone clicks the review in MSO mistaking it is Stack Overflow then to get the Stack Overflow review page they do at least two more clicks to get to Stack Overflow review. This reduce those clicks to a single one. It also makes both the sites look consistent.

Comment: Is the "Meta Reviews" section new or have I just been ignoring it this whole time?

Comment: I guess it new I noticed it yesterday

Comment: I think SE was seeing that meta.X/reviews were being clogged, and are just pulling attention to them.

Comment: @Kev it is new :)

Comment: MS review queues were (almost) empty every time I visit them. Why do we need a link from the main site there? I would be for removing it, not for adding the same, quite misleading cross-site link to meta as well. I agree with your consistency proposal, but disagree with the need of such link at all (if it's the only intended cross-site link).

Comment: There are more cross site links like in your SO profile page we have a link to meta user and in meta we have a link to the main user. I created this mostly for the consistency part as it looked odd to me. I don't mind having the links as there are in the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 11):

I haven't noticed this before, so it may be an experimental way of driving users to Meta and/or Meta review queues.

For congruency, it probably would be a good idea to add a link back to main site reviews on the Meta page if this is/becomes a permanent change.

In the meantime, however, I've written [a userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/8066-link-to-main-site-reviews) that adds it (it should work on all sites, but let me know if it doesn't).

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Link to Main Site Reviews
// @author         AstroCB
// @description  Adds a link to main site reviews from the Meta page
// @version        1.0
// @namespace      http://greasyfork.org/
// @include        *://meta.stackoverflow.com/review
// @include        *://meta.*.stackexchange.com/review
// @include        *://meta.serverfault.com/review
// @include        *://meta.superuser.com/review
// @include        *://meta.askubuntu.com/review
// ==/UserScript==
var siteTitle = /Review - (?:Meta\s(.*)|(.*)\sMeta)/.exec(document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText);
if (siteTitle[1]) {
    siteTitle = siteTitle[1];
} else {
    siteTitle = siteTitle[2];
}
var siteURL = /meta.(.*)/.exec(window.location.href)[1];
var dashboardItem = '<div class="dashboard-item"><div class="dashboard-count"></div><div class="dashboard-summary"><div class="dashboard-title"><a href="//' + siteURL + '">Main Site Reviews</a></div><div class="dashboard-description">Visit the review queues on ' + siteTitle + '.</div></div><br class="cbt"></div>';

document.getElementsByClassName("review-dashboard-mainbar")[0].innerHTML += dashboardItem;
```

Comment: I tried with TamperMonkey in chrome but not working for me..